# Which gotchas to look out for when adapting a Leica screw mount lens to an L-mount camera?

Tags: lens-adapter, screw-mount, m-mount

Why: I am on a lookout for a compact wide lens to use with a full-frame L-mount digital camera. Size and weight matter to me.

I saw a nice lightweight old prime for Leica screw thread mount, and I reckon even with a converter it should be smaller than current equivalents built for L-mount.

I don’t mind using old manual lenses with corresponding implications, but would really rather not lose much more sharpness and quality to the adapter.

Some options I found:

- Get an adapter straight from screw to L-mount. — Seems hard to find, so far I spotted only one adapter<sup>1</sup>, it’s fairly cheap but the absence of competition is worrying and reviews seem pretty bad (most of the old ratings apparently are for another item, listing switcharoo typical for Amazon).
- Get two separate adapters from respectable makers instead: one from screw to M, another from M to L. — I’d expect double conversion to be bulky, but some adapters from screw to M seem compact enough<sup>2</sup>. Not sure how solid such a contraption would feel…

<sup>1</sup> I saw [Fotasy M39 to L mount adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0071UNCT8)

<sup>2</sup> Like, for example, [Voigtlander Leica Screw Mount to Leica M Bayonet Adapter 50-75](https://www.pch.be/en/voigtlander-bague-adaptatrice-ltm-leica-m-pour-50-et-75mm)

Comment: I’m inclined to roll back any edits that place too much stress on products mentioned. Although answers along the lines of “yes, this/that product is good/bad” have their right to exist and may be practical, I expect that more general answers will provide more value. Hence the products are very much secondary to the question, I linked them in the end (so that the text gets fully read first) and did not mention any brand names on purpose. For product reviews there are too many other resources…

Comment: Hi Anton. That's certainly your right, but link text or references that say "this thing" that don't really tell the reader what it is, or worse, just bare URLs that **require** readers to go off-site to get context about what you're talking about, aren't very reader-friendly.

Comment: Hi Scott. I’ve edited some phrasing and styled footnotes in a more traditional way, but I still want them to be footnotes. I find that a link encountered in a block of text tends to prompt a click and disrupt flow, they are fine in some circumstances (e.g. with essential information, when Wikipedia uses a term that could legitimately be new to the reader, or when sufficient reader commitment can be expected that they follow the link and then return back to finish the question), but in other circumstances a good old footnote is better. Hopefully that works

Comment: One reason for clear URLs was to make it obvious that there are no affiliate codes there, but now I remembered that SE adds its own… facepalm. I still believe that, if gotten to the end without having anything to respond with but willing to dig deeper, the reader would have to follow those links regardless of whether they’re labeled with products or not (unless they had to deal with _those exact_ adapters and they recognize the names, the chance of which is so vanishingly small that I didn’t really consider it).

Comment: I can appreciate your viewpoint, and especially thanks for the concern re: no affiliate links, greatly appreciated. The footnote edits read much cleaner, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an L mount camera, but lots of experience with stacked adapters on Sony E and Nikon Z mounts. I'd definitely recommend two (or more) high-quality stacked adapters over a single cheap one.

I've had sub $20 adapters that fit well without any play, but those were the exception. But I often use a good quality Nikon/Contax Rangefinder to Leica M adapter together with a Leica M to Nikon Z adapter, and the stacked adapters work well and without any play.

As an added benefit, you could use advanced M-to-L adapters if/when they become available. For example, there are close-focusing adapters with a helicoid, or even an AF adapter like the Techart PRO (currently Sony E only, but I hope it will appear for other mounts).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience and the last point about future improvements in M to L conversion is something I hadn’t thought of!

Comment: Only thing to watch for, I guess, is whether thread-to-M and M-to-L adapters can have any mutual incompatibilities for some construction-related reason (probably unlikely?). I’ll do some more research in that direction, will accept the answer later, not to discourage someone with same adapter combo from answering